# Architecture of a project in iphone

Tags: iphone, architecture

I'm developing a project for iDevice. I'll explain the architecture of my project, and I would like some feedback.

My project is a typical iPhone application : list of item --> detail.

**STEPS:**

1. I made a singleton to store information .
2. I send an asynchronous request to receive list of items (not detailed), when the request finishes loading, I store the result in a string in singleton and I post a notification ("loading terminated").
3. In other object I "catch" this notification, parse the result stored in singleton, store the parse result in an array in singleton and I post notification ("parse terminated").
4. In other object, I "catch" the notification and I display result in a table view.
5. When a cell is selected, I do the same thing (with other name of notification and other variable in the singleton for detailed item)

I use this architecture because my project needs to be generic and extensible.
It is a good idea to do it in this way? Are there better options?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit like a Model View Controller http://maniacdev.com/2009/10/a-quick-explanation-of-mvc/
I don't know if you need another object to do step 3.  The data is just going into the singleton anyway.  Might be best to have a response processor handle getting the results from 2 and then do the processing from 3 and then send it to the singleton.

Essentially:
- make the synch request and set a delegate to handle the response
- perform all the processing and formatting of the response and save to singleton
- singleton notifies it's delegates of a change
- objects subscribed as a delegate to the singleton perform their action, in this case, display data

check out the link and read up a bit on MVC

Comment: thank you for replaying, I do not know many things about the MVC model (my friends are Zend developers,they explained some details) but I think I'm in the right direction. thank you very much for the link I'll see what i can learn with it .thank you.